# Какие параметры выставить для функции argon2id?

Tags: криптография, шифрование, криптоаналитика, режимы-шифрования

Использую LUKS 2 для шифрования системных дисков. Возник вопрос - какие нужно выставить параметры для функции преобразования паролей argon2id чтобы обеспечить надежную защиту от брутфорса. Стандартная утилита линукс для установки ОС с помощью которой и шифровались диски предлагает такие параметры:

- Количество проходов (Time cost) 4
- Используемая память (Memory) 248936 (??? видимо киллобайт)
- Кол-во параллельных потоков (Threads) 2

Как понять насколько этих параметров достаточно и если не достаточно, то до каких значений их увеличить?

Энтропия пароля составляет 133 бита.